# I need a regex that matches a letter equals a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that matches for example c=2 and another regex that matches a=3. 
The numbers are not important, they could be 1,2,3,4, etc. The letters are very important.
I need to search those expression in a query string.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://regexr.com

Comment: Try at [Regexer](http://regexr.com)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're looking for seems to be:

```
a=(\d+)
```

If you remove the + only one digit is allowed otherwise at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer I got is this one /c\=[0-9]+/ and it works as a charm! Thank you guys anyways

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean `search expression in query string`?
Regex for matching single letter as simple `[a-zA-Z]`